# how to concat two variable in array index ??? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

how to concat array index value as if i have two var

```
 $string='helloworld';
```

and

```
$number=1
```

how would i concat them in aray value like $array[$string+$number]=$value(some value variable)  but it give me result like $array[1]=

```
  $string="helloworld;
    $number=1;
    $array[$string+$number]=$value;
```

result,

```
  $array[1]=...
```

i tried it by all ways by using , too but it does not work

hopes for your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` adds numbers. `.` concatenates strings.

```
echo "Hello " . "world!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaeck this out

```
$string="helloworld"; // missing closing "
$number=1;
$array[$string . $number]=$value;  // replace + with . for concatination
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging the above two answer...

```
$string="helloworld";
$number=1;
$array[$string . $number]=$value;
```